# SlidingMenu and ViewPager with API13 (Honeycomb)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-3.0-honeycomb, slidingmenu

I´m experiencing a weird problem with SlidingMenu Library and ViewPager when they are running on devices with Android 3.2 (Honeycomb).

The problem appears when we "toggle" the SlidingMenu to show the Menu that is hidden on the left of the app. When we do this, both ContentView and BehingContentView stops responding to touch events.

Thinking that this was a problem related to my application, I downloaded the last version of ABS and SlidingMenu library and configured a new project using the built-in example that comes with the SlidingMenu and, for my surprise, the same behavior occurred with the ViewPager example.

These are the steps that I did:

1. Configure an Emulator using *API Level 13* and *7" WSVGA (Tablet)*;
2. Download *ABS* and *SlidingMenu* from GIT;
3. Setup a new Project, using the compatibility library *android-support-v41* (Also tested with android-support-v4);
4. Solved the problem '*getSupportActionBar() is undefined*' as described here: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/145;
5. Run the '*Example Application*' and choose '*ViewPager*' example;
6. Swipe pages to the right and to the left, **without** opening the menu;
7. Open the menu. See that the lists don´t scroll as expected;
8. Close the menu. See that the viewpager doesn´t responds to touch events anymore;

Notice that this behavior was reported only on Android 3.2 devices. We have the same application running on 2.x and on 4.x devices, without this problem.

Also, noticed that the Example Application that was downloaded from Google Play doesn´t have this problem.

Does anybody have any advice? Thanks a lot!

**Edit 1**

Tested on a real device, and confirmed the Behavior. Does anybody have an advice?

Comment: hrmm, I want to try this one out but when I went to the SDK manager I couldn't find a ROM for anything in the 3.x range...

Comment: OK installing the sdk gets the rom in, testing now...

Comment: I'm not having the same problem with the same set up, sorry, you'll need to post more of your code. you activity and the two fragments...

Comment: Hi @Pork. Thanks for your comments. Are you sure that you executed the example exactly as I said? [Here](http://goo.gl/DuCF8) is a link with the whole Eclipse project and also a video that proves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I'll check it out, as long as it compiles under IntelliJ I'll test it, I don't use eclipse.

I'm also using the previous version of ABS not current...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using the following work-around.

Replace these lines in SlidingMenu.java:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void manageLayers(float percentOpen) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) return;
```

with:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public void manageLayers(float percentOpen) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) return;
```

Comment: And also mine, Thanks a gazillion.